# How can I determine if csc.exe compile was successful

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I am trying to compile some c sharp files on the go using a batch file in windows.

Here is the `.bat` file

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe /out:the.exe %1
the.exe
```

My files have a `Console.Read()` call to stop the window from closing and for user to see the output of the execution. The problem I have is that if the compilation fails for some reason the window shows the compilation problem and closes immediately since it never reaches the `Read()` call.

I can use `pause` at the end there in `.bat` file but then I need to press key twice to close the window if the compilation/execution succeeds.

What I would like to know is if the compilation is successful or not. If it were successful then execute the `the.exe` or if it was not then don't execute the executable, instead `pause` or something else to stop the window so that I can see the error(s).

Comment: does the compiler tool `csc.exe` return an error code? if so, you could append `&& the.exe || pause`; `&&` and `||` are conditional command separators, the first one executes the following command in case of error code `0` (no error), the second one in case of an error (non-`0` return code); to find out whether an error code is returned, put `echo %ErrorLevel%` after the `csc` command line and run the script (directly from command prompt) with and without provoking a compilation error; restart the command prompt each time to ensure the error state is reset...

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too but the returned output is a string starting with Microsoft licensing stuff etc and then a bunch of disclaimer etc. And then any errors there might be. One solution is to parse the output and look for keywords like "warning" or "error" but that feels like a hack and using a sword to knit a sweater. There has to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Ah shoot the ErrorLevel is what I needed. Thanks a ton! If you can submit as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: ErrorLevel will give you just success/fail (usually enough if you just need to fail early). If you building more of IDE/editor integration -  output of compiler is quite standard and parsing should not be a problem. You generally turn off licensing/version info for batch/script builds with "/nologo" to get just error/warning info.

Comment: Woha. This question has been... enlightening. I am still new to native work. This is not really any thing as complex as that. It's just a two line batch file to reduce a 3 step process of compilation and execution into one. But yeah that helped! And you're right I don't need that much detail in error levels, just a simple fail/pass will do fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the compiler tool `csc.exe` returns an error code (`ErrorLevel`), you could append `&& the.exe || pause` like this:

```
"C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:exe /out:the.exe "%~1" && the.exe || pause
```

`&&` and `||` are conditional command separators. The first one executes the following command in case of no error, that is return code `0` (no error); the second one in case of an error (non-`0` return code).

Note that this approach can only distinguish compilation success or failure. There may occur warnings which might not be reflected in the returned error code.

---

To find out whether an error code is returned which can be accessed by the built-in variable `ErrorLevel`, put `echo %ErrorLevel% & pause` after the `csc.exe` command line and run the script, once with and once without provoking a compilation error. For this to work, you need to ensure that the error state is reset -- either by restarting the command prompt each time, or by resetting it to `0` explicitly, by executing `cmd /C exit 0` before each of your attempts.